# How to update soap action in HTTP header?

Tags: java, soap, jboss, wildfly

Incoming request contain next Content-Type:

```
Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="testAction"
```

In JBoss 5.1 works very well, in WildFly 8.2 server answers with error "The given SOAPAction testAction does not match an operation."

If action="urn:testAction" then it works both - JBoss and WildFly.

How can I add "urn:" prefix to action on server side? I have added SOAPHandler and tried to change in SOAPMessageContext, but it read only (values not changed on update), in SOAPMessage I didnt found anything that would be worth to change.